# PHP Ranking Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm

I have a website that is going to rank users based on points they have earned for doing certain activities. This is my database structure:

**pointsentered**
1. ID
2. Email
3. Code

**pointvalues**
1. ID
2. Code
3. Title
4. Value

I have a file that connects to **pointsentered** and submits the user-selected to it. The "Code" field corresponds to the **pointvalues**.

In **pointvalues**, the "Title" corresponds to the name of the event they completed. The code is a simple alpha-numeric code that corresponds to that specific event and the value it holds. "Value" is fairly self explanatory, as it holds the point value that the event relates to.

Essentially, I want to have a script that
1. Ranks all of the users (who have different emails) based on entered points in **pointsentered** (but grabs points from **pointvalues** based on the "Code")
2. Shows how many points the user has attained. It relates to the user's email.

Obviously, I am not looking for someone to do this for me, I am just looking for some guidance on how to get started, as I am lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have not yet attempted to do this because I am not sure of where to start, what functions to use etc. I am not looking for someone to do it for me, just somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to achieve with a simple query along the lines of:

```
SELECT pe.Email, SUM(pv.Value) as 'total_points' FROM pointsentered pe
JOIN pointvalues pv ON pe.Code = pv.Code
GROUP BY pe.Email
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

What's going here is you have two tables `pointsentered` and `pointvalues`. The `pointsentered` table contains the `Email` (pe.Email) of the person who was awarded points. Also in that table is a `Code` (pe.Code) which corresponds to a row in the `pointvalues` table. So we can query against the `pointsentered` and `JOIN` the `pointvalues` table to get a list of all awarded points, the email of the person who was awarded, and the number of points awarded. We can also apply an aggregate function to the point values (SUM) and group by the persons Email, yielding a list of all unique Emails along with the total number of points awarded to that Email, starting with the highest number of total points (DESC).

Comment: Thanks for the swift response... Could you just clarify the different parts to this? For example, the "pe.email" and "pv.Value" etc.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks. So when you have "pe.Email", and "pv.Value", etc. I can just write "Email" or "Value?"

Comment: you can as long as the column names are not ambiguous, when joining multiple tables its nice to give the table names aliases so you can easily and explicitly declare which column and which table you are referencing

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused. Can you explain once more how to use them? I now understand that pe = pointsentered and pv = pointvalues

Comment: I suggest doing some research on MySQL queries, specifically JOINS, aliases, and aggregates....http://dev.mysql.com/doc/